# Base64 encoding of Crc32c (long) value

Tags: java, base64, guava, google-cloud-storage, crc32

Working on a google cloud storage projectm, I am trying to caclculate the Crc32c value and get the base64 encoding of the long value return by crc32c algorithm. To calculate crc32c I'm using

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/crc32c-java/blob/master/src/com/google/cloud/Crc32c.java

```
  Crc32c crc32c = new Crc32c();
  crc32c.update(byteSource.read(), 0, byteArrayLength);
  long crcValue = crc32c.getValue();
  byte[] bArray = String.valueOf(crcValue).getBytes();
  String mEncodedCrc = BaseEncoding.base64().encode(bArray);
```

// GCSReturnedCrc is the encoded string returned by google cloud storage

```
 assertEquals(GCSReturnedCrc, mEncodedCrc);
```

// Results

```
 java.lang.AssertionError: expected [MjY0MDc0ODQwNQ==] but found [nWafdQ==]`
```

Other related links: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/hashes-etags#_JSONAPI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expected hash is too long; CRC32C is defined as exactly 4 bytes, but the Google Crc32c implementation returns a long.  It does this to have compatibility with `java.util.zip.Checksum` and to avoid signedness issues with putting a 4-byte quantity in a signed int.  Instead you must remove the first four leading bytes via:

`Arrays.copyOfRange(Longs.toByteArray(crcValue), 4, 8);`

I also opened a pull request against crc32c-java which may help avoid this problem in the future:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/crc32c-java/pull/2

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused. You're base64 encoding the *string* form of the CRC32C hash's `long` value. Is that really correct? It just seems unlikely to me, as the main reason for base64 encoding something is because it's *not* in a readable form such as a `String`. It seems more likely that you should be base64 encoding the 4 bytes of the CRC32C hash itself (it's a 32-bit hash function).

You can get that like this:

```
...
byte[] crcBytes = Ints.toByteArray((int) crc32c.getValue());
// byte[] crcBytes = crc32c.getValueAsBytes(); (method that was just added)
String base64 = BaseEncoding.base64().encode(crcBytes);
```

FYI, we're [releasing](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/detail?r=c20d7397dd89acc5e27e33bf5aff0ca0f316d587) `Hashing.crc32c()` in Guava 18, which should make this even easier.

```
byte[] crc32c = byteSource.hash(Hashing.crc32c()).asBytes();
String base64 = BaseEncoding.base64().encode(crc32c);
```

Comment: Thanks for adding `Hashing.crc32c`!  This avoids the original issue entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a bit harder yourself: When the encoded values don't match, why not decode them back and look at them:

```
Long.parseLong(new String(BaseEncoding.base64().decode("MjY0MDc0ODQwNQ==")))
```

returns `2640748405`. This looks fine.

```
BaseEncoding.base64().decode("nWafdQ==")
```

returns the bytes in hexadecimal 9D,66,9F,75, and converting them back into a String depends on the Charset used. With UTF-8 you get `�f�u`. With no charset you get a `String` representing a number.

OTOH your snippet looks fine... so start a debugger or add some debugging output.

Btw., I'd suggest to avoid locale-dependent methods like `String#getBytes`.

Comment: Yeah Sting.getBytes is not a good option here.I replaced it with Longs.toByteArray(value). But still not getting it right.Anyway
thank you very much for the support.

Comment: @BhathiyaSupun Note that both methods produce a `byte[]`, but in a completely different way. I'd go for `String#getBytes(charset)`, which is platform-independent. Did you output `crcValue`?